# MySQL - Count rows in main table with some condition and equals specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, assignment-operator, multiple-tables

I have two table and first named **table1**:

```
ID  |  Name    |  Type | isActive | isDeleted | 
-----------------------------------------------
1   |  item 1  |  4    |  1       |  0        |
2   |  item 2  |  2    |  1       |  0        |
3   |  item 3  |  1    |  1       |  1        |
4   |  item 4  |  1    |  1       |  0        |
5   |  item 5  |  1    |  1       |  0        |
6   |  item 6  |  3    |  1       |  0        |
7   |  item 7  |  1    |  1       |  0        |
8   |  item 8  |  2    |  1       |  0        |
9   |  item 9  |  1    |  1       |  0        |
10  |  item 10 |  1    |  1       |  0        |
```

AND second named **table1_meta**:

```
ID  |  table1_id  | options    | value
------------------------------------
1   |  1          | dont_ask   |  1   
2   |  2          | dont_ask   |  1
3   |  5          | dont_ask   |  1
4   |  6          | dont_ask   |  1
5   |  8          | alwasys_ask|  1
6   |  9          | alwasys_ask|  1
7   |  1          | is_flagged |  1
8   |  2          | is_flagged |  0
9   |  3          | is_flagged |  0
10  |  4          | is_flagged |  0
11  |  5          | is_flagged |  0
12  |  6          | is_flagged |  1
13  |  7          | is_flagged |  0
14  |  8          | is_flagged |  0
15  |  9          | is_flagged |  0
16  |  10         | is_flagged |  0
```

I'm trying to count rows in **table1** where certain specific criteria is met, some of these conditionals.

The WHERE condition must contain these criteria:

```
table1.type = 1 and table1.isActive = 1 and table1.isDeleted = 0 and table1_meta.options = 'is_flagged' and table1_meta.value = 0
```

and this:

```
table1_meta.options = 'dont_ask' and table1_meta.value = 1
```

and this:

```
table1_meta.options = 'always_ask' and table1_meta.value = 1
```

so, how can I do that?

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eb27b

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer of my question.

the query is:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS total FROM
        (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table1 t1,
               table1_meta t1meta
        WHERE  t1.type = 1
               AND t1.isactive = 1
               AND t1.isdeleted = 0
               AND t1meta.options = 'is_flagged'
               AND t1meta.value = 0
               AND t1.id NOT IN (SELECT table1_id
                                 FROM   table1_meta tm
                                 WHERE  tm.options = 'dont_ask'
                                        AND tm.value = 1)
        UNION
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table1_meta tm,
               table1 t1
        WHERE  t1.id = tm.table1_id
               AND tm.options = 'always_ask'
               AND tm.value = 1) x
```

Thanks anyway, Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to count rows in the first table.  Here is one way using subqueries:

```
select count(*)
from table1 t1
where t1.type = 1 and t1.isActive = 1 and t1.IsDeleted = 0 and
      exists (select 1
              from table1_meta tm
              where t1.id = tm.table1_id and tm.options = 'is_flagged' and tm.value = 0
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1_meta tm
                  where t1.id = tm.table1_id and
                        tm.options = 'dont_ask' and tm.value = 1
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from table1_meta tm
              where t1.id = tm.table1_id and
                    tm.options = 'always_ask' and tm.value = 1
             );
```

This has a separate subquery for each condition on the meta table.

Comment: Yes, the first table is the main table and I'm trying to count rows in this table. Thanks for your answer but I couldn't see '**always_ask**' condition in the query. I need to count rows with all condition. Thanks again.

Comment: I couldn't explain what I need, I guess. Sorry for my English. I need to count all rows in the table1 except marked as '**dont_ask**' but the results must (can be change other conditions) alway contain marked as 'always_ask'. The above query doesn't provide it.